# Is possible to change path to server certificate in AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

I have a problem to use my server certificate in CloudFront of AWS. When I added my server certificate I didn't know that if I'm going to use it in the CloudFront, I needed to add the param *--path /cloudfront/*.
Is it possible change only this parameter without delete and add again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can:

```
$ aws iam update-server-certificate 
          --server-certificate-name <value>
          --new-path <value>
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/update-server-certificate.html